# erro Target class [SendMailNewsLetter] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Sou iniciante no laravel e estou com uma dificuldade que não consigo resolver. Está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Target class [SendMailNewsLetter] does not exist.
```

O que devo fazer? Já procurei na net, mas sem sucesso. Desde já, agradeço pela atenção.

Para melhor compreensão, a seguir vai o código.

***HTML:***

```
<form action="enviar" method="post">
     {{csrf_field()}}
     <div class="form-row">
         <div class="col-lg-8 form-group">
             <input type="email"
                    class="form-control input"
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Seu email"
                    data-msg="Por favor digite um email válido" />
             <div class="validate"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
             <div class="text-center">
                 <button class="btn-cor-especial" type="submit">Ok</button>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="mb-3">
             <div class="sent-message">Sua mensagem foi enviada. Obrigado!</div>
             <div class="loading">Carregando</div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

***Rota:***

```
 Route::post('enviar','SendMailNewsLetter@mailNewsLetter');
```

***Controller:***

```
class SendMailNewsLetter extends Controller
{
    public function mailNewsLetter(Request $request)
    {
        dd("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: o erro acontece ao exibir ou enviar o formulário? talvez facilite se você colocar o controller inteiro

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente o nome do arquivo dentro da pasta `app\Http\Controllers` esta com nome diferente em questão de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, por exemplo, a classe você escreveu

```
SendMailNewsLetter
```

E no arquivo você acidentalmente escreveu:

```
SendmailNewsLetter.php
```

Veja que no arquivo o "M" em mail esta minúsculo, em sistemas operacionais como Linux os nomes de arquivos, pastas, etc, são case-sensitive, por isso tem que usar corretamente, em Windows não é sensível ao caso.

As outras possibilidade são:

- Você confundiu e escreveu o nome errado mesmo
- Colocou o arquivo em uma pasta errada
- Você coloca a rota em um [grupo nas rotas com namespace](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups), que é baseado no caminho da pasta e não deve ter colocado na pasta conforme isso.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer desta forma:

```
Route::get('envio-email', function () {

    $user = new stdClass();
    $user->name = 'Ricado Santana';
    $user->email = 'xavier_123@outlook.com.br';

    /*Visão do navegador*/
    return  new \App\Mail\SendMail($user);
 //   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send( new \App\Mail\SendMail($user));
});
```

Ao executar o comando: `php artisan route:list`, é listada a rota

C:\xampp\htdocs\erpsistemas\TeenCoachLaravel>php artisan rout:list

```
+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI         | Name         | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+------------+
|        | POST     | envio-email |              | Closure | web        |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+------------+
```

Mas, gostaria de adicionar um controle para capturar o e-mail do usuário com Request.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema. No arquivo de rota, eu alterei

***De:***

`Route::post('envio-email','SendMailNewsLetter@mailNewsLetter');`

***Para:***

`Route::post('envio-email', 'App\Http\Controllers\SendMailNewsLetter@mailNewsLetter');`